# Can't access Apache outside LAN

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I have been trying to set up apache to use as a small personal web server, but I am running into a problem. I can access apache from inside the local network on port 8073 (my isp blocks port 80) and all seems to work. Then i go to whatsmyip.org , get my ip and try to access apache from outside (on port 8073) and it just trys to load for a while, then says it can't connect. I have set up port forwarding on my router and allowed port 8073, but I can't get it to connect. I have even gone to canyouseeme.org and it is able to see my service on port 8073 so I finally gave up and decided to ask the many people smarter and more experienced than me!

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If canyouseeme.org is showing a service....that just doesn't make sense. Do you have a friend that you could have check it from their computer?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Thank you! I viewed it through a proxy and it came up just fine. But now I'm curious, why wouldn't it work when I tried to access it from inside my network?

Comment: I don't know... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use your public IP to search for your own computer when you're behind a network interface.

Network interfaces are (as the name suggest) a "box" between 2 nodes and network directions (IP) are used by the vectors between the nodes.

The following graph will clarify my statement.

[image: IPs]

So, you can ask for your www service from your PC calling localhost. Or from the internet calling your public address. As you can see you cannot ask for your public IP from your computer, unless you use a proxy which is the same thing as ask from any other computer outside your LAN.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

Try Forward TCP port 3389, the default port for Remote Desktop Connection, to the IP address of the home computer you want to access from outside the network.